# Using wildcards in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

I am trying to use wildcards in a formula to count cells in a table column which contain text and not `""`

I tried the following methods:

- String comparison

```
Dim g As Integer

g = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ws1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("ColumnA").DataBodyRange, ""*?"")
```

- Using a tilde failed:

```
Dim g As Integer

g = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ws1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("ColumnA").DataBodyRange, ""~*?"")
```

- Using ASCII characters below returned 0:

```
g = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ws1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Column1").DataBodyRange, Chr(34) & Chr(63) & Chr(42) & Chr(34))
```

Comment: Try using `"?*"` as the criterion.

Comment: Also is `"" text` a +1 count?

Comment: Using "?*" rather than ""?*"" worked... I thought special characters always had to be prefixed in some way, e.g. the semicolon in:  Range(Var1 & ":" & Var2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried and tested:

```
Public Function not_qt(ByVal rng As Range) As Integer

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim counter As Integer: counter = 0

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If Not cell Like Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) Then
                counter = counter + 1
                'cell.Offset(0, 1) = counter   '<- Only for illustration purposes
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    not_qt = counter

End Function
```

---

[image]